# how to filter by iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has 2 columns. the second column is one of only a few values. I want to make a method that returns a dataframe where only the rows where that column had a specific value are included.

I had this working with this this code:

```
def filterOnName(df1):
    d1columns = df1.columns
    return df1[df1[d1columns[1]] == "Jimmy"]
```

Seems quite convoluted doesn't it? I guess there's  a pandas method called iloc that should clean this up abit but I'm having trouble implementing it. Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
def filterOnName(df1):
    return df1[df1.iloc[1] == "Jimmy"]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First argument of `.iloc` is for rows. To get the second column, you'll need:

```
df.iloc[:, 1]
```

where `:` means "all rows".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nifty little trick with `iloc`.

We can use `df.columns.get_loc()` to supply the column as an index value to be used in `iloc`:

```py
df.iloc[<row#>, df.columns.get_loc("<colName>")]
```

PS: We can also go the other way, with `loc`!

```py
df.loc[df.index[<row#>], "<colName>"]
```